# Functioning App on local server fails on Azure

Tags: azure, openiddict, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have an Angular Web app with an API that is functioning perfectly (well, as perfectly as any app under development functions) on my local server, but when I migrate it and its associated databases to an App Service on Azure every /api call fails with 500.

So thinking that the problem was with the databases I altered the connection strings on my local development server to point to the Azure databases. I found one small problem this way, I has mispelled the username in the connection string. SO I fixed that and it runs perfectly on my local server while accessing the Azure databases, but as soon as I run it on the Azure App Service using the same connection strings every call to /api fails with Internal Server Error 500.

All regular pages are served perfectly and Angular routing works just fine. Only accessing content from the DB fails. I have been at this for a few days and have no idea what to do next. Any advice welcomed.

I am using OpenIddict for authentication so I tagged that, but I can't see anyway that is relevant. Oddly though, and there is a clue here somewhere, the authentication call to "/connect/token" works and returns a valid token, but "/api/..." URLs do not.

I am using Asp Net Core 2.1 if that is relevant.

**More Information**

I tried the detailed logs as suggested, but they were hardly detailed. But I did note one interesting item. In the error there was the following information:

```
Requested URL:    https://mysite.azuurewebsites.net/api/accounts/getusers
Physical Path:    D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\accounts\getusers
```

Now this app is using MVC so there is no such Physical Path. The Controller is decorated with:

```
[Route("api/accounts")]
```

and the Action is decorated as:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Somerole")]
    [HttpGet("GetUsers"), Produces("application/json")]
```

It seems to me the route mapping is failing. But this works beautifully on my local development computer. What could be different on the Azure App Service? Is there some special setting I need to set in the portal to allow MVC? I can't imagine why the portal should care about such matters.

**Even More Information**

Using Postman, if I access /api/someValidUrl with a valid Bearer token I get a 500 error. If I remove the Authorization header then I get a 401 returned.

I started off by saying I didn't think it had anything to do with OpenIddict, but maybe I was wrong. My Authorization Controller simply creates the token. All the checking for validity is done by OpenIddict.

**A Huge Clue**

I added an ExceptionHandler and then used Postman to make an API request and that yielded the following exception:

```
<h1>Error: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.</h1>   
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I found an explanation [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8c011020-2976-44fb-9a45-19da46c150b8/idx20803-unable-to-obtain-configuration-from-amp39pii?forum=WindowsAzureAD) but I don't fully understand this but it looks as though MS middleware on Azure is incorrectly trying to interpret it as an Azure AD request. The only thing I know for sure is I do not have a file called IdentityModelEventSource.cs in my project.

For reference https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration returns:

```
{
    "issuer": "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/",
    "token_endpoint": "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/connect/token",
    "jwks_uri": "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/jwks",
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "password"
    ],
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "email",
        "profile",
        "roles"
    ],
    "claims_supported": [
        "aud",
        "exp",
        "iat",
        "iss",
        "jti",
        "sub"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post"
    ],
    "claims_parameter_supported": false,
    "request_parameter_supported": false,
    "request_uri_parameter_supported": false
}
```

Perhaps with this information someone can point me in the right direction.

**New Startup.cs**

I took Pinpoint's advice and changed from JWT. The new Startup follows:

```
    using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SIAngular.DBContexts;
using SIAngular.Models;
using SIAngular.Services;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SIAngular
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            this.env = env;
            SIDBConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SIDB");
        }

        public static string SIDBConnectionString;

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            SymmetricSecurityKey _ssk = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection"));

                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

            services.AddCors();

            // Register the Identity services.
            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = true; config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

            // Configure Identity to use the same JWT claims as OpenIddict instead
            // of the legacy WS-Federation claims it uses by default (ClaimTypes),
            // which saves you from doing the mapping in your authorization controller.
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
            });

            services.AddOpenIddict()

                // Register the OpenIddict core services.
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                        .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
                })

                // Register the OpenIddict server services.
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC services used by OpenIddict.
                // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
                // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
                options.UseMvc();

                // Enable the token endpoint.
                options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

                options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
                options.DisableScopeValidation();

                // Note: the Mvc.Client sample only uses the code flow and the password flow, but you
                // can enable the other flows if you need to support implicit or client credentials.
                options.AllowPasswordFlow();

                // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                options.RegisterScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);

                // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

                options.AddSigningKey(_ssk);

                })
                .AddValidation();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

            services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, SqlPasswordHasher>();

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
            );

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions { HotModuleReplacement = true });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
            {
                builder.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                        name: "spa-fallback",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Comment: Turn on failed request tracing, fire up a few requests to `/api/` and check the traces - see here (you only need the portal setting to capture 500s - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at that now. Analyzing logs on Azure seems to be something of a dark art. I have a call in to Lord Voldemort :)

Comment: I believe you can even see the FREBs inline now in the portal blade, no need for Kudu. Anyway it's more of an IIS thing rather than Azure thing.

Comment: If you don't share your ASP.NET Core logs, it's impossible to help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#azure-app-service-provider should put you on the right track.

Comment: @Pinpoint It appears to me that the exception is being generated in the call made at JwtBearHandler.cs line 87. I'm not sure what it's doing but if the GetConfigurationAsync() throws an exception, shouldn't JwtBearerHandler catch it?

Comment: @MartinHorton no: the error you're seeing is a "fatal" exception indicating the JWT bearer handler is unable to download the discovery document from OpenIddict's configuration endpoint. You should take a look at the inner exception to figure out what's going on. If you can't make the MSFT handler work, consider switching back to the default token format with the OpenIddict validation handler: it doesn't use discovery.

Comment: I don't understand why my code works perfectly on my development computer but only fails when deployed to Azure. But I've given up trying to fix that so I have stopped using JWT. My latest Startup.cs is about to be added to the  original question. But this now leads to an exception InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found but as far as I can see I have followed the OpenIddict samples closely.

Comment: Are you API actions decorated with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`?

Comment: No,  they aren't, but then they weren't on my development computer either. I have also discovered that OpenIddict also needs to add some tables to the database. I added those tables to my aspnetIdentity database. I've started the entire project over again using the QuickApp template for Aspnet Core 2 and Angular 6. I'll get the Authentication and Authorization working and then move all the original app into the new project. Is there a good book anyone can recommend on OpenId and OpenIddict? All of the documentation I have read already assumes you know what everything means.